# Actionscript 3.0 TextField cursor change when above TextField

Tags: actionscript-3, mouse-cursor

My scene has a TextField object.
I set up my TextField as DynamicText because I need to change it programmatically.

How do I prevent mouse cursor change to I-Beam form when it's above TextField?
Also, user of my flash application is able to select text of this TextField using mouse cursor. I would like to disable this behavoiur too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the TextField properties panel, there is an icon that reads "Selectable", you need to uncheck it, and you will disable both.

EDIT: The icon is right below the "Anti-Alias" drop down, first in row. There is a Ab (the b is selected/highlighted) inside.

If you want to do this by ActionScript, the code is:

```
myTextField.selectable = false;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6

You are looking for the property `selectable`